# Traveling to U.S. while waiting for I-130 (spouse visa)

Tags: visas, usa

Me (U.S. citizen), my wife (Japanese citizen), and 2 kids (dual citizenship) currently live in Japan, and we're currently waiting for a I-130 visa for my wife so we can move to the U.S. (applied last March)

We're planning a 3-week trip this October to visit family in the States. From what I read, it's fine to visit the United States while waiting for a I-130 visa as long as we can "convince the immigration officer we're not planning on staying".

How does one "convince" the officer we're only going to be in the states for a few weeks? Is there specific paper work we should bring? Specific things we should mention to them?

Comment: Nothing more than usual when you travel. It's the exact same bar.

Comment: @littleadv I'd disagree.  Part of the reason of getting married is the desire to live together.  Thus the OP's wife has to prove to immigration that even though her spouse  lives in the US, she will  leave the US when she says she will. However, her ties are *to* the US - but she just doesn't yet have permission to reside in the US.  This is different from someone proving to immigration that their ties are outside of the US.

Comment: @PeterM: "even though her spouse lives in the US" The question says the OP currently lives in Japan, not the US.

Comment: @user102008 Yeah, on re-reading the question I see that I missed that.  However, I think my main point is still valid. The spouse has ties to OP, not necessarily to Japan, thus IMHO there is an increased risk for the spouse not returning to Japan.  About the only thing I can see that would stop the illegal stay would be that it probably screws up the I-130 application. Or perhaps that the children are held hostage by in-laws in Japan.

Comment: @PeterM: It doesn't screw up the I-130, and in fact they can file I-485 in the US at any time if they change their mind and decide to stay. So I agree that the officer has to take into account the risk of that happening.